# spliting data at specified index in two vertical columns

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have array of 20 integers  `int[] numbers`;

I want to display those numbers in two html table columns where first columns should break at 11 number and continue rendering on second, for example

```
Numbers | Some other data
---------------------------
1    12 |  Some data a
2    13 |  Some data b
..   14 |  Some data c
10   15 |
11   16 |
```

I tried something like this

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>Numbers</td>
       <td>Some other data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   @{
       int numberscounter= 0;
       foreach (var item in numbers){

          if (numberscounter< 11) { 
           numberscounter++;
          <tr>
             <td>@item.Number</td>
             <td>@item.SomeOtherData</td>
          </tr>
         }
         else {
            <tr>    
                <td>@item.Number</td>
                <td>@item.SomeOtherData</td>
            </tr>   
         }
       }
   }
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The above code will render rows, you want columns right? You might consider either ordering by the order you want to render the pairs in or rendering using indexes instead and adding 10 to the index of the items in the right hand column. Will you always have 20 items or will it be a varying number?

Comment: why split on 11 if you have 20? seems a little odd. also why have a `numberscounter++` if the `item` in this case is a number going up from 1-11 in the `foreach` loop?

Comment: @Charlex It will always be 20.

Comment: @Adween, I've put by mistake counter++ outside loop, fixed now.

Comment: @user1765862 Good i'm glad you fixed it. why not complete this post by adding your answer :)

Comment: @Adween it's not fixed. I've tried. please complete.

Comment: @user1765862 To get help i think you need to look at your question as it doesn't really make sense. You say that numbers is an array of integers. It cant be as when you loop it in the `foreach` it now has 2 properties `Number` and `SomeOtherData`. Do you want to break on the actual number 11 or the index in the array of 11. Also if you now have the numbers split into 2 separate columns. will there be 2 separate column for the `SomeOtherData` fields? I cant "complete" if i don't understand what you are trying to do, sorry :(

Comment: I want to split at number 11.

Comment: and what exactly is the numbers object, and what do you want to happen to the `SomeOtherData` attached to each number?

Comment: SomeotherData should be some dummy data, no matter at all.  numbers object is array of ints, from zero to twenty (0-20).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't elegant and I still don't understand what you are trying to do. for example what the some other data is and how you will display it, but to get what you are after (just splitting the numbers at 11 into 2 columns) you could do the following:

Get rid of the array it is not needed and do the following with a for loop

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Numbers</td>
        <td>Some other data</td>
    </tr>

    @for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++){
        <tr>
            <td>@i.ToString()</td>
            <td>@(((i + 11) <= 20) ? (i + 11).ToString(): "")</td>
            <td>Some other data here (notsure how this is generated)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**EDIT** 
(after comments): Ok so you want to use the numbers you have already in the unknown object and keep them in the 2 separate columns....

How about this

```
@{
    //These are my test values. you will need to edit them with your values
    int[] intarray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
    var Below11 = intarray.Where(x => x <= 11).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
    var Above11 = intarray.Where(x => x > 11).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
}


<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Numbers</td>
        <td>Some other data</td>
    </tr>

    @for (int i = 0; i <= Math.Max(Below11.Count(), Above11.Count()) - 1; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@(i < Below11.Count() ? Below11[i].ToString() : "")</td>
            <td>@(i < Above11.Count() ? Above11[i].ToString() : "")</td>
            <td>Someother data</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your time but it seems you did not understand me. I do not want to generate those numbers, those are already stored in property numbers, I just want to break them at number eleven and continue render like I describe in my question.

Comment: @user1765862 Can you provide what object you are iterating over as I thought it was a integer array... It obviously is not if the numbers are a properties in an object.

Comment: @user1765862 i have made an edit to show you how to do it on a pre-populated array. is this more what you were thinking?